# Are SET statements within INSERT syntax valid SQL

Tags: sql

I have been using queries such as `INSERT INTO table SET foo='alice', bar='bob'`, which work within MySQL, and I have been wondering, is that query valid with all SQL server implementations, or is it a MySQL unique implementation? I have had a look for MSSQL syntax, but it only references `(foo,bar) VALUES ('alice','bob')` as valid. I would have tested it further myself, but I don't have access to many other server implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not valid standard SQL.

As far as I know MySQL is the only DBMS supporting this strange syntax.

Btw: here are some DBMS to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com